# Using QGIS generated web map in Android app

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis2web, qgis-android

I am on Windows 10 (x64 machine). Using QGIS' (version 3.12) qgis2web plugin, I have created a web map of my location of interest. The map contains OSM basemap with overlayed points shapefile (classified into 5 categories). There are more than 2 million point locations.

In the web app, there are index.html and JS and CSS source files in a directory. The app runs locally and displays the map fine. Now, I would like to show the same web app in my Android application (Android Studio, Java).

I thought of using Android's WebView class, or is there any other way to do the same?

I am also concerned about my web app as it is very slow while zooming-in and out- of the map.

Comment: Would your app work in Google Chrome [?]

Comment: If you meant the web app (created byQGIS), then yes, it works fine in Google Chrome. The only issue is it is super slow when I zoom-in and out, as explained above. I was more interested to know how could I display such a map in theAndroid app..

Comment: " I am also concerned about my web app as it is very slow while zooming-in and out- of the map. Any thoughts/suggestions would be highly appreciated!". You should use "cluster" for so many points. Greetings